# How to get Facebook user phone number in android

Tags: android, facebook

I want to get Facebook user basic information, i am getting ,But i am not able to get Facebook user phone number.If You know please help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think facebook is allowing any application to take user_phone details. please check this link https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/447/

Comment: My Bad, I am deleting the comment!

Answer (score 24):

There is no way to get the phone number of a Facebook user via the Graph API. Even not if the user set it to public.

Have a look at the docs at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/#fields